# Event code in worksheet stops working once a macro on button is triggered

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook where code in a worksheet gets triggered when an event happens. I also have a button in this worksheet that 'exports' the data from this workbook to a new workbook. That part works, but when I want to work in the original file, it no longer triggers any events in the workbook, unless I close Excel and re-open it.

*How can I, after the button has been hit and the new file is created, work in the other file and still have the events working?*

A useful note perhaps:
When exporting the data to a new workbook, I don't remove the existing macro in the workbook. I searched for a way without success.

**Code of the worksheet**

```vb
Option Explicit 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("1:9")) Is Nothing Then
        'This ensures that these rows gets skipped in the code

    Else
        If Target.Count > 1 Then 'Check who last modified it
        Else
            Cells(Target.Row, "H").Value = Application.UserName
        End If
    
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("UGCImagePath1, UGCImagePath2, UGCImagePath3")) Is Nothing Then
            'Checks if field is edited in UGCImagePath1 and then adds formulas in the next two fields

            Sheets("Data Validation Sheet").Range("PreviewFormula").Copy
            Sheets("PDP_CMS_Product_Data").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 1).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        
            Sheets("Data Validation Sheet").Range("ResetPreviewFormula").Copy
            Sheets("PDP_CMS_Product_Data").Cells(Target.Row, Target.Column + 2).Select
            Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas, Operation:=xlNone, _
              SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End If

    End If
    
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("GoToCell")) Is Nothing Then
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:="", SubAddress:= _
          ActiveSheet.Range("GoToCell").Value, TextToDisplay:=Range("D2").Value
        Selection.Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
        ActiveSheet.Range("GoToCell").Font.FontStyle = "Bold"
        ActiveSheet.Range("GoToCell").Font.Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        ActiveSheet.Range("GoToCell").Font.Color = vbBlack
    End If

    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**Code of the 'export button'**

```vb
Sub ExportPDButton()

    'Start Export
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_Index_Transpose").Visible = True
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_CompSet_Transpose").Visible = True
    Sheets(Array("PDP_CMS_CompSet_Transpose", "PDP_CMS_Product_Data", "PDP_CMS_Copy", _
      "PDP_CMS_Index", "PDP_CMS_Index_Transpose")).Copy
        
    'Structure PDP_CMS_CompSet_Transpose
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_CompSet_Transpose").Select
    Rows("1:2").Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_CompSet_Transpose").Name = "PDP_CMS_Component_Settings"
    
    'Structure PDP_CMS_Product_data
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_Product_Data").Select
    
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_Product_Data").Shapes.Range(Array("CBShowMenuPD", "CBCallOutPD", _
      "CBBenefitChildrenPD", "CBBenefitParentsPD", "CBVideoPD", "CBWITBPD", _
      "CBSpecificationsPD", "CBTechHighlightPD", "CBMarqueePD", "CBFAQPD", "CBUGCPD" _
      , "CBBrandPD", "ShowComponentSettingsSheet", "ExportPDButton")).Delete
    Rows("1:8").Delete
    Rows("1:50010").Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
        
    Range("A1:DL50009").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$DL$50009").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:= _
      "<>TRUE", Operator:=xlAnd
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.AutoFilter

    'Structure PDP_CMS_Copy
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_Copy").Select
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_Copy").Shapes.Range(Array("CBShowMenuPD", "CBCallOutPD", _
      "CBBenefitChildrenPD", "CBBenefitParentsPD", "CBTechHighlightPD", "CBMarqueePD", "CBFAQPD", "CBUGCPD")).Delete
    Rows("1:8").Delete
    Rows("1:50010").Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False

    'Structure PDP_CMS_Index_Transpose
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_Index_Transpose").Select
    Rows("1:1000").Copy
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_Index").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Sheets("PDP_CMS_Index_Transpose").Name = "PDP_CMS_Index"
    
    'Closing the sheets in the original workbook for user interface purposes
    Workbooks("NewPDP V.05").Sheets("PDP_CMS_Index_Transpose").Visible = False
    Workbooks("NewPDP V.05").Sheets("PDP_CMS_CompSet_Transpose").Visible = False

    'Save Export of PDP
    Workbooks(Workbooks.Count).Sheets("PDP_CMS_Product_Data").Select
    Dim DateOfToday As String
    Dim TimeOfExport As String
    ExportPDP = "ExportPageDesignerPDP"
    DateOfToday = Format(Date, "yymmdd")
    TimeOfExport = Format(Time, "hhmmss")
    ActiveWorkbook.Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show ExportPDP & DateOfToday & TimeOfExport

End Sub
```

I would like to continue working without closing Excel.

Comment: Try to disable events in the button code and re-enable at the end of it. It's probably triggering the event code but not finishing it so it gets disabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA is single threaded. You cannot have your code and event code running simultaneously. You have to be very careful when modifying Application level flags. You will need proper error traps to ensure everything ends in a sane state.

I would remove action code from your event. Pull everything out of the `Worksheet_Change` event in to a new sub called something like `OnWorksheetChange`.

Then in the export section we need to follow a similar pattern. Setting `Application.EnableEvents = True` at the end of your export code will ensure that it always goes back to listening for events. (Which answers your main question)

So the event looks like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    OnWorksheetChange Target

errHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub OnWorksheetChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' Your code goes here
End Sub


Public Sub ExportPDButton()
    On Error GoTo errHandler
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    ' Your code goes here
    
errHandler:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

NOTE: Any time you have to use `On Error Resume Next` that code block needs to live in it's own subroutine to avoid spagetti. If you follow this rule then your main subs, with the error traps, will always work. Error skipping is limited to the procedure level so you don't have to set `On Error` multiple times in one subroutine.

Consider splitting each of the event sections where you compare target in to their own procedures. Then your event could have the logic in it and the actions separate.